# Multiply everything by 2 inside brackets in python using return function

Tags: python, python-3.x

Okay so I am creating this program were to find the surface area of a rectangler prism. I want to have everything in the brackets multiplied by 2 after the math in the brackets is exucuted. Only problem is that I am using the return function and I keep getting an error the 2 is not callable. Below is my code.

```
def vsa(l,w,h):
      return 2(l*w + h*l + h*w)
```

Comment: `2*(l*w + l*h + h*w)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `*` symbol making it `2*(l*w + l*h + h*w)`